# Any suggestions on how to improve the sentence?

Tags: grammar

Any suggestions on how to improve the sentence (more specifically the words in **bold**)?

I'm writing to you because I would like to participate in a special contest, **which I noticed** at the back of my ticket for the exhibition Royal Portraits at the National Gallery in London.

Comment: "*on* the back"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you break this into multiple sentences, since it's getting pretty long and it needs further explanation.  Look at this:

> I recently attended the Royal Portrait Exhibition at the National Gallery in London.  On the back of my ticket, I noticed a [give a little more information than "special contest" here].  I'm writing to you because I would like to participate in this contest.

It's better to eat a meal one bite at a time.  Similarly, it's better to separate concepts into different sentences.

Note also as user3169 that this contest is *on* the back of the ticket, not *at* it.  Also, if you are going to say the "exhibition Royal Portraits" you need to say "exhibition *of* royal portraits".  If that isn't the name of the exhibition, you will not capitalize royal portraits.  If it is, you should state the name exactly as written on the ticket, which is probably as I have it in my example.

Comment: You could also say "...for the exhibition "Royal Portraits" at the National Gallery in London.", as long as that is the actual name of the exhibition, and not "Royal Portrait Exhibition".